# GWTP displays default place on application start even if url say to go to other place

Tags: gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

I wonder how to change gwtp behaviour.
When I start gwt app (enter app url in browser) it always displays for me `default place`. But when I enter url as follow: `localhost/app#settings` gwtp should open place `Settings`, but unfortunatelly it displays me `Default` place.

Url in web browser address points to `Settings` but the view is from `default` place.

I would like to gwtp display for me the view from url.

Here is my configuration:

```
public class UiModule extends AbstractGinModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {

    bind(AppView.Binder.class).in(Singleton.class);
    bind(Footer.Binder.class).in(Singleton.class);
    bind(GatekeeperProtectedMenuPanel.Binder.class).in(Singleton.class);



    install(new GinFactoryModuleBuilder().build(MenuEntryFactory.class));

    }
```

---

```
public class ClientModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
    bind(RestyGwtConfig.class).asEagerSingleton();

    install(new DefaultModule.Builder()//
        .defaultPlace(Routing.HOME.url)//
        .errorPlace(Routing.ERROR.url)//
        .unauthorizedPlace(Routing.LOGIN.url)//
        .tokenFormatter(RouteTokenFormatter.class).build());
    install(new AppModule());
    install(new GinFactoryModuleBuilder().build(AssistedInjectionFactory.class));

    bind(CurrentUser.class).in(Singleton.class);
    bind(IsAdminGatekeeper.class).in(Singleton.class);
    bind(UserLoginGatekeeper.class).in(Singleton.class);



    // Load and inject CSS resources
    bind(ResourceLoader.class).asEagerSingleton();

    }

}
```

---

```
public class AppModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
    install(new UiModule());

    // Application Presenters

    bindPresenter(AppPresenter.class, AppPresenter.MyView.class, AppView.class, AppPresenter.MyProxy.class);
    bindPresenter(HomePresenter.class, HomePresenter.MyView.class, HomeView.class, HomePresenter.MyProxy.class);
    bindPresenter(ErrorPresenter.class, ErrorPresenter.MyView.class, ErrorView.class, ErrorPresenter.MyProxy.class);
    bindPresenter(TestPresenter.class, TestPresenter.MyView.class, TestView.class, TestPresenter.MyProxy.class);
    bindPresenter(PagePresenter.class, PagePresenter.MyView.class, PageView.class, PagePresenter.MyProxy.class);
    bindPresenter(SettingsPresenter.class, SettingsPresenter.MyView.class, SettingsView.class, SettingsPresenter.MyProxy.class);
    bindPresenter(FilesPresenter.class, FilesPresenter.MyView.class, FilesView.class, FilesPresenter.MyProxy.class);
    bindPresenter(AdminAreaPresenter.class, AdminAreaPresenter.MyView.class, AdminAreaView.class, AdminAreaPresenter.MyProxy.class);

    bindPresenter(LoginPresenter.class, LoginPresenter.MyView.class, LoginView.class, LoginPresenter.MyProxy.class);
    }
}
```

This happens when I have `GateKeeper` on place's presenter.

Here is code:

```
public class UserLoginGatekeeper extends UserLoginModel implements Gatekeeper {
    private final CurrentUser currentUser;

    @Inject
    UserLoginGatekeeper(CurrentUser currentUser) {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canReveal() {
        return currentUser.isLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

In my main app presenter I execute asynhronous call to server to check is user login. If so I set client variable `currentUser.setLoggedIn(true);`. Base on this `Gatekeeper` allow access to restricted part of app.

I think the problem is that my asynhronous call is triggered to late. And GWTP redirect to default place.

Here is my app presenter code:

```
public class AppPresenter extends TabContainerPresenter<AppPresenter.MyView, AppPresenter.MyProxy> implements AppUiHandlers, CurrentUserChangedHandler, AsyncCallStartHandler, AsyncCallFailHandler,
    AsyncCallSucceedHandler {

    @ProxyStandard
    public interface MyProxy extends Proxy<AppPresenter> {
    }


    public interface MyView extends TabView, HasUiHandlers<AppUiHandlers> {
    void refreshTabs();

    void setTopMessage(String string);

    void setLoginButtonVisbility(boolean isVisible);
    }


    @RequestTabs
    public static final Type<RequestTabsHandler> SLOT_REQUEST_TABS = new Type<>();

    @ChangeTab
    public static final Type<ChangeTabHandler> SLOT_CHANGE_TAB = new Type<>();


    public static final NestedSlot SLOT_TAB_CONTENT = new NestedSlot();

    private static final LoginService service = GWT.create(LoginService.class);
    private final PlaceManager placeManager;
    private final CurrentUser currentUser;

    @Inject
    AppPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view, MyProxy proxy, PlaceManager placeManager, CurrentUser currentUser) {
    super(eventBus, view, proxy, SLOT_TAB_CONTENT, SLOT_REQUEST_TABS, SLOT_CHANGE_TAB, RevealType.Root);
    this.placeManager = placeManager;
    this.currentUser = currentUser;
    getView().setUiHandlers(this);
    onStart();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
    service.isCurrentUserLoggedIn(new MethodCallback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable exception) {
        MaterialToast.fireToast("Fail to check is current user logged in " + method + " " + exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Method method, Boolean response) {
        currentUser.setLoggedIn(response);
        getView().setLoginButtonVisbility(response);
        }
    });
    };

    @ProxyEvent
    @Override
    public void onCurrentUserChanged(CurrentUserChangedEvent event) {
    getView().refreshTabs();
    }

    @ProxyEvent
    @Override
    public void onAsyncCallStart(AsyncCallStartEvent event) {
    getView().setTopMessage("Loading...");
    }

    @ProxyEvent
    @Override
    public void onAsyncCallFail(AsyncCallFailEvent event) {
    getView().setTopMessage("Oops, something went wrong...");
    }

    @ProxyEvent
    @Override
    public void onAsyncCallSucceed(AsyncCallSucceedEvent event) {
    getView().setTopMessage(null);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLogoutButtonClick() {
    service.logout(new MethodCallback<Void>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable exception) {
        MaterialToast.fireToast("Fail to logout " + method + " " + exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Method method, Void response) {
        MaterialToast.fireToast("You have been Succefully logout");
        PlaceRequest request = new PlaceRequest.Builder(placeManager.getCurrentPlaceRequest()).nameToken(Routing.Url.login).build();
        placeManager.revealPlace(request);
        currentUser.setLoggedIn(false);
        getView().setLoginButtonVisbility(false);
        }

    });

    }
}
```

---

**Working solution:**

```
/**
 * 
 */
package pl.korbeldaniel.cms.client.gin;

import gwt.material.design.client.ui.MaterialToast;

import org.fusesource.restygwt.client.Method;
import org.fusesource.restygwt.client.MethodCallback;

import pl.korbeldaniel.cms.client.place.Routing;
import pl.korbeldaniel.cms.client.security.CurrentUser;
import pl.korbeldaniel.cms.client.service.LoginService;

import com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.Bootstrapper;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManager;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.shared.proxy.PlaceRequest;

/**
 * @author korbeldaniel
 *
 */
public class MyBootstrapper implements Bootstrapper {
    private final PlaceManager placeManager;
    private final CurrentUser currentUser;
    private static final LoginService service = GWT.create(LoginService.class);

    @Inject
    public MyBootstrapper(PlaceManager placeManager, CurrentUser currentUser) {
    this.placeManager = placeManager;
    this.currentUser = currentUser;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBootstrap() {
    GWT.log("OnBootstrap");
    service.isCurrentUserLoggedIn(new MethodCallback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable exception) {
        MaterialToast.fireToast("Fail to check is current user logged in " + method + " " + exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        placeManager.revealErrorPlace("Fail to check is current user logged in " + method + " " + exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Method method, Boolean response) {
        // MaterialToast.fireToast("1Current user is logged in: " +
        // response);
        currentUser.setLoggedIn(response);
        if (response == true) {
            placeManager.revealCurrentPlace();
        } else {
            placeManager.revealPlace(new PlaceRequest.Builder().nameToken(Routing.Url.login).build());
        }
        }
    });
    };

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, your backend call is asynchronous and most likely the `UserLoginGatekeeper` code will run before the backend call returns and the user gets redirected to the default page.

There are two solutions:

1. Use a dynamically generated host page (index.html) and set a javascript variable to the user details by the backend. You can read out the userdetails in a custom [Bootstraper](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/get-started/Bootstrap-Code.html) implementation and set the `CurrentUser`.
2. If you don't want to use a dynamically generated host page, you can also move the backend call `isCurrentUserLoggedIn` intot he custom `Bootstrapper` implementation and in the `onSuccess` callback reveal the first page (like in the above linked GWTP documentation)

Comment: Thanks. I've followed You 2 solution. I will place `Bootstrapper` code in question.